# Document Icon not getting updated in Google Drive UI integration

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I have an app which has Google Drive UI integration enabled.

We have updated both the application icon and document icon in Drive UI integration tab in Google Drive API.It is mentioned by Google that the

> Document icons are deprecated. Your application icon appears next to shortcut files. A set of standard icons is used for other file types.

But for my app, the application icon and document icon are different. Application icon is updated for the users. But the document icon changes is not reflected, it is still the old icon.